Accessing sharepoint onedrive folder contents via python
I am trying to access the contents of a SharePoint folder. I have tried multiple APIs offered by Microsoft but all of them appear to be outdated/not working.
I need to retrieve file names and contents using Python.
Anybody has experience with this?
Tried using the following:

import pysharepoint as ps (log in problems)
from azure.identity.aio import EnvironmentCredential
from msgraph_core import BaseGraphRequestAdapter (msgraph_core does not appear to be importing correctly)
from onedrivesdk import get_default_client (outdated)


when you tried import pysharepoint as ps or any of the others where did it specifically fail ?

Also,  have you tried this: https://pypi.org/project/sharepoint
